# "set value in php"

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

This is my part of my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'lib/shopify.php';
//require_once 'csv.php';
$t  = "bac2486aa2b31aa5aed1fdd62e77a4ae";
$sc = new ShopifyClient("mine-329.myshopify.com/", $t, API_KEY, SECRET);
if (!isset($t)) {
    if (!isset($_GET['signature'])) {
        $url = $sc->getAuthorizeUrl("read_orders");
        header('Location: ' . $url);
    }
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $accTok = $sc->getAccessToken($_GET['code']);
        echo "token = " . $accTok;
        exit;
        $orders = $sc->call('GET', 'admin/orders.json', array(
            'published_status' => 'published'
        ));
        foreach ($orders as $order) {
            echo $order['id'];
            echo $order['email'];
        }
    }
}
if (isset($t)) {
    $orders               = $sc->call('GET', 'admin/orders.json', array(
        'published_status' => 'published'
    ));
    $myarray              = array();
    $list[]               = array(
        'Name',
        'Email',
        'Financial status',
        'Paid at',
        'Fullfillment Status',
        'Fullfilled at',
        'Accepts Marketing',
        'Currency',
        'Subtotal',
        'Shipping',
        'Taxes',
        'Total',
        'Discount code',
        'Discount Amount',
        'Shipping Method',
        'created at',
        'Lineitem quantity',
        'Lineitem name',
        'Lineitem price',
        'compare at price',
        'Lineitem sku',
        'Lineitem requires shipping',
        'Lineitem taxable',
        'Lineitem fulfillment status',
        'Billing Name',
        'Billing Street',
        'Billing Address1',
        'Billing Address2',
        'Billing Company',
        'Billing City',
        'Billing Zip',
        'Billing Province',
        'Billing Country',
        'Billing Phone',
        'Shipping Name',
        'Shipping Street',
        'Shipping Address1',
        'Shipping Address2',
        'Shipping Company',
        'Shipping City',
        'Shipping Zip',
        'Shipping Province',
        'Shipping Country',
        'Shipping Phone',
        'Notes',
        'Note_attributes',
        'VAT',
        'Cancelled at',
        'Payment Method',
        'Payment Reference',
        'Refund',
        'Vendor',
        'Id',
        'Tags'
    );
    $list                 = array_filter($list);
    $empty_note_attribute = "";
    if (empty($order['note_attributes'])) {
        $empty_note_attribute = "";
    } else {
        $empty_note_attribute = $order['note_attributes'];
    }
    $empty_discount_codes = "";
    if (empty($order['discount_codes'])) {
        $empty_discount_codes = "";
    } else {
        $empty_discount_codes = $order['discount_codes'];
    }



$countryCodes = array('United States' => 'US','India'=>'IN');

    foreach ($orders as $order) {

        $orders_lineitem = $order['line_items'];
        $lineitemcount   = 0;
        foreach ($orders_lineitem as $lineitem) {
            /*
            Fulfillment Status
            */
            $fulfill_status = "";
            if (empty($order['fulfillment_status'])) {
                $fulfill_status = "pending";
            } else {
                $fulfill_status = $order['fulfillment_status'];
            }
            /*
            Lineitem Fulfillment Status
            */
            $fulfillment_status = '';
            if (empty($order['fulfillments'][0]['created_at'])) {
                $fulfillment_status = "pending";
            } else {
                $fulfillment_status = $order['line_items'][0]['fulfillment_status'];
            }
            $variants          = "";
            $variants          = $sc->call('GET', "admin/variants/" . $lineitem['variant_id'] . ".json", array(
                'published_status' => 'published'
            ));
            $requires_shipping = "false";
            if ($lineitem['requires_shipping']) {
                $requires_shipping = "true";
            }
            $lineitem_taxable = "false";
            if ($lineitem['taxable']) {
                $lineitem_taxable = "true";
            }
            //** Accepts Marketting **

            $accepts_marketting = "no";
            if ($order['buyer_accepts_marketing']) {
                $accepts_marketting = "yes";
            }
            $shipping = '';
            if (count($order['shipping_lines']) > 0) {
                $shipping = $order['shipping_lines'][0]['price'];
            }
            /* 
            Fulfilled at
            */
            $created_at = '';
            if (count($order['fulfillments']) > 0) {
                $created_at = $order['fulfillments'][0]['created_at'];
            }
            /*  
            Refunded Amount 
            */
            $refund_price = '';
            if (count($order['refunds']) > 0) {
                foreach ($order['refunds'] as $refund) {
                    $refund_price += $refund['transactions'][0]['receipt']['paid_amount'];
                }
            }
            if ('pending' == $fulfill_status || 'partial' == $fulfill_status) {
                $created_at = '';
            }

            if ($lineitemcount == 0) {
                array_push($list, array(
                    $order['name'],
                    $order['email'],
                    $order['financial_status'],
                    (($order['financial_status'] != 'partially_refunded') && ($order['financial_status'] != 'refunded') && ($order['financial_status'] != 'authorized')? $order['created_at'] : null),
                    $fulfill_status,
                    $created_at,
                    $accepts_marketting,
                    $order['currency'],
                    $order['subtotal_price'],
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $shipping : 0),
                    $order['total_tax'],
                    $order['total_price'],
                    $empty_discount_codes,
                    $order['total_discounts'],
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_lines'][0]['code'] : null),
                    $order['created_at'],
                    $lineitem['quantity'],
                    $lineitem['name'],
                    $lineitem['price'],
                    $variants['compare_at_price'],
                    $lineitem['sku'],
                    $requires_shipping,
                    $lineitem_taxable,
                    $fulfillment_status,
                    $order['billing_address']['name'],
                    $order['billing_address']['address1'],
                    $order['billing_address']['address1'],
                    $order['billing_address']['address2'],
                    $order['billing_address']['company'],
                    $order['billing_address']['city'],
                    $order['billing_address']['zip'],
                    $order['billing_address']['province'],
                    $order['billing_address']['country'],
              $order['billing_address']['phone'],
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['name'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['address1'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['address1'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['address2'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['company'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['city'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['zip'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['province'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['country'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['phone'] : null),
                    $order['note'],
                    $empty_note_attribute,
                    (($order['line_items'][0]['tax_lines'][0]['price'] != '0') ? $order['total_tax'] : null),
                    $order['cancelled_at'],
                    $order['payment_details']['credit_card_company'],
                    $order['checkout_id'],
                    (($refund_price > 0) ? $refund_price : 0),
                    $lineitem['vendor'],
                    $order['id'],
                    $order['tags']
                ));
            } else {
                array_push($list, array(
                    $order['name'],
                    $order['email'],
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    $empty_discount_codes,
                    '',
                    '',
                    $order['created_at'],
                    $lineitem['quantity'],
                    $lineitem['name'],
                    $lineitem['price'],
                    $variants['compare_at_price'],
                    $lineitem['sku'],
                    $requires_shipping,
                    $lineitem_taxable,
                    $order['line_items'][0]['fulfillment_status'],
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    $lineitem['vendor'],
                    '',
                    $order['tags']
                ));
            }
            $lineitemcount++;
        }
    }
    $order  = $_GET;
    $list[] = array_to_csv_download($myarray, // this array is going to be the second row
        "numbers.csv");
    $list   = array_filter($list);
    array_to_csv_download($list);
    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
}
function array_to_csv_download($list)
{
    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
    foreach ($list as $row) {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
        //print_r($row); die;
    }
    fclose($output);
}
?>
```

And this is my output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXBLy.jpg

Now I got value of country like India or united states..etc.(i.e., corresponding country name). Now how to set IN or US. (I.E., if India means it will print IN and likewise)

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: Got a bit of a syntax error going on here.. Are you sure this will compile?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I edited Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't `orders.json` give back more fields than just country? If not, you should have an authoritative list of all possible values and their respective mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from the full code.  I believe this should do what you're after.

```
<?php
require_once 'lib/shopify.php';

// YOU NEED TO POPULATE THIS WITH FULL DATA
$countryCodes = array('UNITED STATES'=>'US','INDIA'=>'IN');

//require_once 'csv.php';
$t  = "bac2486aa2b31aa5aed1fdd62e77a4ae";
$sc = new ShopifyClient("mine-329.myshopify.com/", $t, API_KEY, SECRET);
if (!isset($t)) {
    if (!isset($_GET['signature'])) {
        $url = $sc->getAuthorizeUrl("read_orders");
        header('Location: ' . $url);
    }
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $accTok = $sc->getAccessToken($_GET['code']);
        echo "token = " . $accTok;
        exit;
        $orders = $sc->call('GET', 'admin/orders.json', array(
            'published_status' => 'published'
        ));
        foreach ($orders as $order) {
            echo $order['id'];
            echo $order['email'];
        }
    }
}
if (isset($t)) {
    $orders               = $sc->call('GET', 'admin/orders.json', array(
        'published_status' => 'published'
    ));
    $myarray              = array();
    $list[]               = array(
        'Name',
        'Email',
        'Financial status',
        'Paid at',
        'Fullfillment Status',
        'Fullfilled at',
        'Accepts Marketing',
        'Currency',
        'Subtotal',
        'Shipping',
        'Taxes',
        'Total',
        'Discount code',
        'Discount Amount',
        'Shipping Method',
        'created at',
        'Lineitem quantity',
        'Lineitem name',
        'Lineitem price',
        'compare at price',
        'Lineitem sku',
        'Lineitem requires shipping',
        'Lineitem taxable',
        'Lineitem fulfillment status',
        'Billing Name',
        'Billing Street',
        'Billing Address1',
        'Billing Address2',
        'Billing Company',
        'Billing City',
        'Billing Zip',
        'Billing Province',
        'Billing Country',
        'Billing Phone',
        'Shipping Name',
        'Shipping Street',
        'Shipping Address1',
        'Shipping Address2',
        'Shipping Company',
        'Shipping City',
        'Shipping Zip',
        'Shipping Province',
        'Shipping Country',
        'Shipping Phone',
        'Notes',
        'Note_attributes',
        'VAT',
        'Cancelled at',
        'Payment Method',
        'Payment Reference',
        'Refund',
        'Vendor',
        'Id',
        'Tags'
    );
    $list                 = array_filter($list);
    $empty_note_attribute = "";
    if (empty($order['note_attributes'])) {
        $empty_note_attribute = "";
    } else {
        $empty_note_attribute = $order['note_attributes'];
    }
    $empty_discount_codes = "";
    if (empty($order['discount_codes'])) {
        $empty_discount_codes = "";
    } else {
        $empty_discount_codes = $order['discount_codes'];
    }

    foreach ($orders as $order) {

        $orders_lineitem = $order['line_items'];
        $lineitemcount   = 0;
        foreach ($orders_lineitem as $lineitem) {
            /*
            Fulfillment Status
            */
            $fulfill_status = "";
            if (empty($order['fulfillment_status'])) {
                $fulfill_status = "pending";
            } else {
                $fulfill_status = $order['fulfillment_status'];
            }
            /*
            Lineitem Fulfillment Status
            */
            $fulfillment_status = '';
            if (empty($order['fulfillments'][0]['created_at'])) {
                $fulfillment_status = "pending";
            } else {
                $fulfillment_status = $order['line_items'][0]['fulfillment_status'];
            }
            $variants          = "";
            $variants          = $sc->call('GET', "admin/variants/" . $lineitem['variant_id'] . ".json", array(
                'published_status' => 'published'
            ));
            $requires_shipping = "false";
            if ($lineitem['requires_shipping']) {
                $requires_shipping = "true";
            }
            $lineitem_taxable = "false";
            if ($lineitem['taxable']) {
                $lineitem_taxable = "true";
            }
            //** Accepts Marketting **

            $accepts_marketting = "no";
            if ($order['buyer_accepts_marketing']) {
                $accepts_marketting = "yes";
            }
            $shipping = '';
            if (count($order['shipping_lines']) > 0) {
                $shipping = $order['shipping_lines'][0]['price'];
            }
            /* 
            Fulfilled at
            */
            $created_at = '';
            if (count($order['fulfillments']) > 0) {
                $created_at = $order['fulfillments'][0]['created_at'];
            }
            /*  
            Refunded Amount 
            */
            $refund_price = '';
            if (count($order['refunds']) > 0) {
                foreach ($order['refunds'] as $refund) {
                    $refund_price += $refund['transactions'][0]['receipt']['paid_amount'];
                }
            }
            if ('pending' == $fulfill_status || 'partial' == $fulfill_status) {
                $created_at = '';
            }

            /*
            Change country to 2-character version using the lookup array above
             */
            $fullCountryName = strtoupper($order['billing_address']['country']);
            if (isset($countryCodes[$fullCountryName]))
                $order['billing_address']['country'] = $countryCodes[$fullCountryName];
            if (isset($order['shipping_address']['country']) {
                $fullCountryName = strtoupper($order['shipping_address']['country']);
                if (isset($countryCodes[$fullCountryName]))
                    $order['shipping_address']['country'] = $countryCodes[$fullCountryName];
            }

            if ($lineitemcount == 0) {
                array_push($list, array(
                    $order['name'],
                    $order['email'],
                    $order['financial_status'],
                    (($order['financial_status'] != 'partially_refunded') && ($order['financial_status'] != 'refunded') && ($order['financial_status'] != 'authorized')? $order['created_at'] : null),
                    $fulfill_status,
                    $created_at,
                    $accepts_marketting,
                    $order['currency'],
                    $order['subtotal_price'],
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $shipping : 0),
                    $order['total_tax'],
                    $order['total_price'],
                    $empty_discount_codes,
                    $order['total_discounts'],
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_lines'][0]['code'] : null),
                    $order['created_at'],
                    $lineitem['quantity'],
                    $lineitem['name'],
                    $lineitem['price'],
                    $variants['compare_at_price'],
                    $lineitem['sku'],
                    $requires_shipping,
                    $lineitem_taxable,
                    $fulfillment_status,
                    $order['billing_address']['name'],
                    $order['billing_address']['address1'],
                    $order['billing_address']['address1'],
                    $order['billing_address']['address2'],
                    $order['billing_address']['company'],
                    $order['billing_address']['city'],
                    $order['billing_address']['zip'],
                    $order['billing_address']['province'],
                    $order['billing_address']['country'],
              $order['billing_address']['phone'],
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['name'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['address1'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['address1'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['address2'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['company'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['city'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['zip'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['province'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['country'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['phone'] : null),
                    $order['note'],
                    $empty_note_attribute,
                    (($order['line_items'][0]['tax_lines'][0]['price'] != '0') ? $order['total_tax'] : null),
                    $order['cancelled_at'],
                    $order['payment_details']['credit_card_company'],
                    $order['checkout_id'],
                    (($refund_price > 0) ? $refund_price : 0),
                    $lineitem['vendor'],
                    $order['id'],
                    $order['tags']
                ));
            } else {
                array_push($list, array(
                    $order['name'],
                    $order['email'],
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    $empty_discount_codes,
                    '',
                    '',
                    $order['created_at'],
                    $lineitem['quantity'],
                    $lineitem['name'],
                    $lineitem['price'],
                    $variants['compare_at_price'],
                    $lineitem['sku'],
                    $requires_shipping,
                    $lineitem_taxable,
                    $order['line_items'][0]['fulfillment_status'],
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    $lineitem['vendor'],
                    '',
                    $order['tags']
                ));
            }
            $lineitemcount++;
        }
    }
    $order  = $_GET;
    $list[] = array_to_csv_download($myarray, // this array is going to be the second row
        "numbers.csv");
    $list   = array_filter($list);
    array_to_csv_download($list);
    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
}
function array_to_csv_download($list)
{
    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
    foreach ($list as $row) {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
        //print_r($row); die;
    }
    fclose($output);
}
?>
```

Comment: I have just changed the code that I believe should be done within your original list.  Please ensure you copy and paste this.  This won't touch the shipping address by the way.

Comment: No problems, glad to be of help!

Comment: Lots and lots of practice :)  Try and get hold of a book that covers PHP5 and work through the various examples in it and then create your own variations to see how things work.  Personally I like the Visual Quickstart books.

Comment: I've updated the above to include code for the shipping.  I learned quite a bit from an earlier version of: http://www.amazon.co.uk/PHP-Web-Visual-QuickStart-Guides/dp/0321733452

Comment: Have a look on here for "country name to iso code" else we're going to be going off topic on this question :)

Comment: here i have .json file which contain all countries "alpha-2" value. So can we include .json file to my above code for fixing my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to have an array of countries names and codes.
Like:

```
$country_codes = array('United States' => 'US', 'India' => 'IN);
```

and then all you have to do is:

```
$code = $country_codes[$country];
```

Comment: @saina: it's county name. Say, ` echo $country_codes['United States']; `

Answer (score 0):

```
$countryCodes = array('India'=>'IN');
if (isset($t)) {
    $orders = $sc->call('GET', 'admin/orders.json', array('published_status' => 'published'));
    $myarray = array();
    $list[]  = array('Shipping Country');
    foreach ($orders as $idx=>$order) {
        if (isset($countryCodes[$order['billing_address']['country']]))
            $list[$idx] = $countryCodes[$order['billing_address']['country']];
        else
            $list[$idx] = null;
    }

}
```

Something like the above should work, however one thing to bear in mind is that you really need some validation on what the value of country will be - United Kingdom, uk, UK, GB, Great Britain for example should equate to UK (or GB).  United states, usa, US and so on will be US.

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on?  The above code is very much out of context (and theoretical).

Comment: Just realised I'm missing some closing brackets - sorry!

Comment: I'd expect that if you were using a "empty()" instead of an "isset()".  Also you've added in closing round brackets and not square ones - try copying the line again and see what happens.

Comment: You need to have: if (isset($countryCodes[$order['billing_address']['country']]))  You have the wrong brackets at the end.  Also do not use empty, you need to use isset.

Comment: The line should show: $list[$idx] = $countryCodes[$order['billing_address']['country']];

Comment: That's not what your original code was trying to do, the abbreviated counties are being placed into $list.  Are you wanting to modify $counties instead?

Comment: Full code would be much better as we'd have the full context.